# Eclipse Project Access Java Core Classes On Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Am running Eclipse on Mac OS X but for some crazy reason it just can't find my Java base classes like ArrayList etc... I just the Install JRE under Preferences and there is a valid JDK that got all the classes correct like point to classes.jar etc... Any idea what can be wrong? And yes I did do a Clean, it just can't build.

Eclipse Helios, latest Java 6, Snow Leopard Mac OS X

Comment: Version of Eclipse? Version of Java? Version of MacOSX?

Comment: Eclipse Helios, latest Java 6, Snow Leopard Mac OS X.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846573/796559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your Eclipse uses the Java JRE and not the JDK. You need to point Eclipse to where your JDK is installed.

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and Add your JDK directory. Then make sure that you uncheck (or remove) the previous JRE. That should allow you to see the base classes.