# Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ant, osx-yosemite

I use OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) and have some java projects which I want to build in Eclipse. Some projects are old and they are in Java 5, 6 and 7. At first, I installed JDK 7 and Eclipse Luna. Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-to-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846573/how-to-get-jdk-1-5-on-mac-osx) thread how to install specific JDK on mac. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/bric3/1163008) script to install JDKs and changed these two lines in order to Yosemite compatibility.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :JavaVM:JVMMaximumFrameworkVersion 14.*.*" ./Resources/Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :JavaVM:JVMMaximumSystemVersion "$osx_version".*" ./Resources/Info.plist
```

by

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :JavaVM:JVMMaximumFrameworkVersion" ./Resources/Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :JavaVM:JVMMaximumSystemVersion" ./Resources/Info.plist
```

Here is content of my `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` directory

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306  8 apr 14:32 1.5.0_30
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238  8 apr 14:36 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1  8 apr 14:36 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59  8 apr 14:36 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

Location of JDK 7 is different and the path is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk`

Default Java version is:

```
AND:bin andr-work$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Here are installed JDKs in Eclipse preferences

[image]

Version 7

[image]

Version 6

[image]

Version 5

[image]

When I want to build projects in java 6 or 7, I don't have any problems with java compiler in Eclipse

[image]

[image]

But I cannot build some projects in java 5 and probably compiler for java 5 is not set properly

[image]

I found [this](http://eyeforthings.blogspot.com/2010/12/on-mac-eclipses-java-compiler-does-not.html) blog post with this problem and solution is

> ...replace the "A" subdirectory with files from someone else's Mac

but I don't know anybody with working these java versions in Yosemite.

I tried to change Execution Environments in Eclipse preferences

[image]

But it didn't help.

**Java Build Path** in project properties is **J2SE-1.5** and I tried to change **Execution environment** by **Alternate JRE**

[image]

but when I save this settings and open it again **J2SE-1.5** is still Execution environment (J2SE-1.5)

Then I tried to add java `source` and `target` in `build.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="build" default="jar">
    <description>
            A build script
    </description>

    <property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.5"/>

    <property name="dist.jar" value="ci-ons.jar"></property>
    <property name="dist.folder" value="dist"></property>
    <property name="src.folder" value="src"/>
    <property name="classes.folder" value="bin"/>

</project>
```

but it didn't help.

Do you have any idea how can i build projects in java 5 in Eclipse in Yosemite?

EDIT:// The problem was JDK 1.5 path referred to CurrentJDK, what was JDK 1.6. I run installation of JDK 1.5 and 1.6 again and now JDK 1.5 is linked with JDK 1.5

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  9 apr 11:01 1.5 -> ./1.5.0_30
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  9 apr 11:01 1.5.0 -> ./1.5.0_30
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306  9 apr 11:01 1.5.0_30
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238  8 apr 14:36 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1  8 apr 14:36 Current -> A
```

In project properties I don't get any warnings of compiler, but apparently JDK 1.5 doesn't have JRE 1.5, because if I open Eclipse preferences Java->Installed JREs->Execution Environments, there is not any JRE 1.5

[image]

and I cannot build projects in Java 5, because I get errors:

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

This is content of `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0_30` directory

[image]

I decided to open new [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535500/install-jdk-1-5-in-osx-10-10-yosemite)

Comment: My understanding is that there is no Java 5 that runs on Yosemite so you are always going to get the warning.

Comment: I dont understand. Why do you think there is not Java 5 that runs on Yosemite? I installed java 5 which is in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions directory

Comment: Most old programs I've seen still work fine if you update the target version to 1.6 or 1.7. What kind of problems does that give you?

Answer (score 2):

I solved mine with just right-clicking the "Java System Library"  in the Project Explorer and chose "Properties". In the "Execution environment" just selected the right Java version.

Answer (score 0):

[eclipse: select your java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l66d.png)

Dyadee solution worked for me also for Windows 10.

Check what version of java you have installed (for windows run CMD: java -version)

Right Click: JRE **System Library** and select **Properties**.

**Execution environment**: here you select the version you have installed - my case was: JavaSE-1.8 (jre1.8.0_144)