# Netbeans looks blurry on mac os x mountain lion on a retina display

Tags: macos, netbeans, java, retina-display

Yesterday i was setting up my new macbook pro with retina display and realize that netbeans looks very blurry. This is something critical for me because i spent from 8 to 10 hours using netbeans everyday. I searched online i found that this is an issue with the jre 1.7 and will work ok with the jre 1.6 provided by apple.

The thing is that i have intalled jre 1.7 on my mac and have not found a way of downgrade my
jre to 1.6, which is not critical for me because i am not a java developer,i only need the jre for running netbeans and do my loved PHP web development.

Please any help on how to downgrade to jre 1.6 from 1.7 in mountain lion.

Comment: I followed the instructions from this website. Now Netbeans itself is running on 1.6 but I am able to run individual Jave EE 7 projects by pointing to 1.7 JVM. Awesome. http://www.hildeberto.com/2013/05/getting-rid-of-blurred-netbeans-in-your.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. It's possible to tell NetBeans to use a different version of Java:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4470872?start=0&tstart=0#21143742

If you still want to downgrade so that the *default* version for all your applications is Java 6, see my comments here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413600/560114

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Retinizer](http://retinizer.mikelpr.com), although it won't increase the resolution of any icons within the app, just any text, as well as the Cocoa GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion. Before upgrading I was using Java 6, and now I'm using Java 7 and saw the ugly font rendering.

However there is a way to fix the font on Netbeans without having to revert back to a previous version of Java.  The issue is that the default Netbeans font "Monospaced 13" maps to different fonts in the two Java versions.  The Java 6 version maps this to "Courier 13", while the Java 7 version maps it to something ugly.  So you can have the nice font rendering by simply changing the default font to be **"Courier 13"** in your Netbeans+Java 7 (Preferences > Fonts & Colors).

More details here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229029

Answer (score 1):

This is incredible simple to fix but I was very hard to me to find the answer.

You have to upload your JDK 7. I had the same problem with JDK 7u25. And fixed the problem downloading the last version 7u72 form [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

So, do some checks first. Run:

`$ java -version`

I was using "java version "1.7.0_25"

Then run the following command to get the route.

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`

You should get, before the upgrade:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

Then install the new version, and you should get the new route with the last command:

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home`

Go to your Applications folder, look for Netbeans (I have the version 8.01), right click "Show Packages Content".

Then navigate to Contents/Resources/Netbeans/etc. and edit netbeans.conf
On that file add the line with th evalue netbeans_jdkhome and put your route.

`netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Done.