# Why is my Netbeans (7.3.1.) blurry with MacOS (10.x) and Retina display?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-7, retina-display, java-6

I just installed Netbeans on my new MacBook Pro with Retina Display. And now everything inside the IDE is blurry (font, ect.).

I've installed Java SE 7.

How can I get it sharp **without downgrading** to old Java SE 6 and loose Java SE 7 for Java developing?

I know there are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495539/netbeans-looks-blurry-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-on-a-retina-display), but this guy doesn't need Java SE 7.

Answer (score 0):

First you need Java SE 6 - the old one. You can download it [here](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39490/apple-java).

Then you have to say your Netbeans to use the right java version like described [here](http://www.hildeberto.com/2013/05/getting-rid-of-blurred-netbeans-in-your.html):

> 1. go to /Applications/NetBeans/, click on the file Netbeans 7.3, open
>      its context menu and select the option "Show Package Contents".
> 2. In the package, navigate to /Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc and edit the file netbeans.conf.
> 3. Uncomment the variable netbeans_jdkhome and set its value like that:
>      netbeans_jdkhome="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home".

That's it.

If you are developing in java you may now run into following error:

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

So keep reading this [article](http://www.hildeberto.com/2013/05/getting-rid-of-blurred-netbeans-in-your.html):

> 1. go to the menu Tools / Java Platforms to see a dialog as shown in the figure below.
> 2. add other JDKs you have installed. My JDK 1.7, for instance, is located at:
>      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_##.jdk/Contents/Home. Yours is probably somewhere there too.

Hope that helps you with this issue and without downgrading your Java SE.

***Attention:*** this won't work with Netbeans 7.4+, because it needs Java SE 7 to run at all.