# Installing Javac on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: java, macos

I want to install Javac on my mac but I can't find a link anywhere. Is it available for mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How install a specific jdk on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently javac has been preinstalled on my computer. Stupid question.

Answer (score 5):

For now, [OSX ships with it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/00-Intro/JavaDevelopment.html).

```
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call it javac, it is just the Java Compiler. You need JDK (Java Development Kit). It will contain all the tools needed for Java Development.

JDK comes pre-installed on new versions of Mac. For more Help on Getting jdk on Mac check [this link](http://java.about.com/od/gettingstarted/a/javamacosx.htm) out.