# JDK 7 installation on mac

Tags: java, macos, java-7

When I try to install the jdk 7 on my mac (with the the jdk-7u40-macosx-x64.dmg), I have the following error :

`Java from Oracle requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later. Your system has Mac Os X Version 10.6.8.`

Any idea of how I can resolve that? It is mandatory for me to upgrade my whole system?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes is mandatory to upgrade to 10.7 at least.
The message is clear enought. 
As suggest @AndreyAtapin this question is a dublicate

Answer (score 0):

No, you can also do it manually.

Just install java to some place like /usr/local/java and set your export path and java-home path.

See also here [How to install a specific JDK on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x)